# jQueryUI Dialog position in Android (Droid Bionic)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, android-browser

I'm working on a web app involving several jQueryUI modal dialogs used for editing single data items.  It works great on the desktop and in MobileSafari, but in Android, the position of the dialog is way off.  It's supposed to be positioned center, but it appears down and to the right, so that only (approximately) the top left quadrant of the dialog is visible.  It's as if jQueryUI is somehow wrong about the size of the viewport, either because Android reports it wrong or because of a bug.  It's not possible to drag the dialog to reposition, either; as expected, the touch drag event scrolls the view instead of moving the content.

When I say Android I actually mean the built-in browser on the Droid Bionic; I don't have any other test devices available.  I'm using jQuery 1.6.2 and jQueryUI 1.8.14.

Is this a bug in jQueryUI, or is there a workaround?  Google has been very unhelpful.